# Difference between sequence and function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Online resources describe a function as a correlation between domain and range values,  while a sequence is just a bunch of numbers correlated with the term.

Isn't this the same thing if you consider the term to be the domain and the sequence value at that term to be the range? What's the difference between a sequence and function?

Comment: Sequences are functions defined on (a part of) the integer line.

Comment: @Didier Isn't that the same thing as a function with an integer domain and a restriction on domain values? Why are sequences used if a function can be used to model the exact same thing?

Comment: @Farhad Because sequences are functions of particular interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be the same thing. Though it's a pita talking about "a function from $\mathbb{N}$, zero inclusive/exclusive, to $\mathbb{R}$. "Sequence" is a bit shorter.